# Generating/Compression unique key

Tags: algorithm, hash, compression

In my work I have many users and each users have set of files in there home directories. Due to some pre defined rules I have given each file a UID (unique identification), based on the user file content and its creation time. But now I came to know that the number of files in user account cannot exceed say 1 million. The current UID is about 32 characters long. Is there any way through which I can bring down my UID to about 6 (ideal condition) character to about 10-12 character long as the current uidl is using lots of space in my NoSQL database.

Current uidl looks like
timestamp.prrocess_whichcreated_it.size

**EDIT**
Let me rephrase the problem. What I actually need is a compressing algo:
For e.g.

I have list of 1,000,000 strings( each unique )and each 32 character long. I need a compress function f, such that F(string) = s2 , where S2 is of length 10 characters and all the S2 strings are uniquely mapped

Comment: Are you looking for a hash function which will run every time you are looking for a UID or a method to change these UID's to the smaller new range?

Comment: @amit: I just want to compress my previous UID, it will be good if i can use the current UID for my task, but it will also be good if i can calculate new. Ideally H(C.UIDL) = newuidl

Comment: Then why don't just sort and replace? sort all UID's, and replace old UID with a new UID indicating the old UID's index in the sorted list. It will be unique and optimal. Or am I missing what you really mean? :|

Comment: @amit: looks like a good idea. I think it should work :)

Comment: I added it as an answer then. I was not sure I understood your question correctly. Glad I did :)

Comment: Your 32 character filenames really use up an appreciable amount of space compared to, say, the files themselves? Is this really worth worrying about?

Comment: @NickJohnson: Main point is the I need to store the file and its "meta data" on NoSQL database where my key would be username.uid does the uid is causing problem because the uid size becomes comparable to meta data.

Comment: why do you think that 32MB per user takes up a "lot of space"? how many files do you actually have and how much space does those descriptors take up?

Answer (score 1):

Sort your UID's and replace the old UID's with a new UID indicating the index in the sorted array of the old UID's

a simplified pseudo code should look like that:

```
sorted <- sort(UID's)
for each file:
  file.UID <- sorted.indexOf(file.UID)
```

Comment: it cannot be done in that way: I should always get my new uid from the previous uid. Therefore I need a function like say H(prev) =  newuid, bcz i cannot just change the previous data as it is present on multiple location

Answer (score 1):

It very difficult to take a UNIQUE id compress it and keep it UNIQUE. You tend to run into collisions.

@amit's suggestion really is the best one. Perhaps his implementation was a bit glib though.

How about you create a table with an AUTO INCREMENTING INTEGER "ID" column and a string/varchar "OldGUID". INSERT all your old/current GUIDs into the table and now you have a 1-to-1 match between the GUID and a shorter/compressed "ID". As you create new GUIDs just INSERT them into the table and you'll continue having the 1-to-1 match so you can switch back and forth between long and short version.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a Unique Identifier, then my first thought goes to [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

However, generic UUID will consume 16 bytes, and is binary format. It does not meat your requirement of 6 characters. Compared to your current method using 32 characters, it "only" saves 50% space.

Therefore, a milder scheme would be to use 64-bit UID (8 bytes) with a general Hash Function. With a good hash, the probability of collision remains fairly reasonable as long as the total number of UID generated is below < 100 millions. If that seems acceptable, then 8-bytes seems pretty close to your space requirement.